# How to get String description/value?

Tags: kotlin

In Kotlin, how to get the raw value of the String?

For example,

```
val value: String = "Adrian"
```

Expected result:

```
"Cannot find value: Adrian"
```

I am coming from Swift and I know in swift it works like this

```
let value: String = "Adrian"
print("Cannot find \(string.description): \(value)")
```

Another example in Swift,

```
let a: String = "b"
print("\(a.description) = \(a)"
///prints "a = b"
```

Im guessing a String extension is needed given I read the Kotlin String documentation and seems none of the choices provides the expected result.
A simple problem but I really can't solve it:(

Comment: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/basic-types.html#string-templates

Comment: But strings don't have a description. Not sure why `string.description` would be `value`.

Comment: @JBNizet, I'm coming from Swift and the value of the string can be obtained from string.description, its an example in Swift. I just wonder whether Kotlin has something similar.

Comment: i.e. getting the raw value of the string.

Comment: As explained in the linked documentation, you can use `"Cannot find ${value}"`, and that will print `Cannot find Adrian`, because the value of the variable `value` is "Adrian". But there is no such thing as `string.description`, because there is no variable `string` being defined anywhere.

Comment: @JBNizet sorry the question seems to be confusing, I have just added another example in Swift, thanks:)

Comment: There is no such thing as a "description" of a variable in Kotlin. Local variable names don't even exist at runtime. If you want something which has a description and a value, use an instance of a class which has a property named description, and a property named value.

Answer (score 0):

This might help you. For this you have to use Kotlin reflection:

Example:

```
data class Person(val name:String)

fun main(){
    val person = Person("Birju")
    val prop = person::name
    println("Property Name: ${prop.name}")
    println("Property Value: ${prop.get()}")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about 
println("value :$value")
You don't need concatination operator(+) to concat strings in kotlin